# Typescript variable can be either type

Tags: typescript, factory-pattern

I have a `packageMessage` factory function, and i need it to return one of two types: `PackagedChannel` or `PackagedGuildChannel` based on the value of a `type` parameter.

**The function:**

```
function packageMessage(id: string, type: PackagedChannelType, name?: string, position?: number): PackagedChannel | PackagedGuildChannel {
    var packaged: PackagedChannel | PackagedGuildChannel;
    packaged.id = id;
    packaged.type = type;
    if (type === 'text') {
        packaged.name = name;
        packaged.position = position;
    }
    return packaged;
}
```

**The types:**

```
type PackagedChannelType = 'dm' | 'text' | 'unknown';
interface PackagedChannel {
    id: string;
    type: PackagedChannelType;
}
interface PackagedGuildChannel extends PackagedChannel {
    name: string;
    position: number;
}
```

however, the function yields a `Property 'name/position' does not exist on type 'PackagedChannel'` error.

**How could i do this?** help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function packageMessage(id: string, type: PackagedChannelType, name?: string, position?: number): PackagedChannel | PackagedGuildChannel {
    return type === 'text' ? { id, type, name, position } : { id, type};
}
```

Or even better, if you want more type safety, you may overload it.

```
function packageMessage(id: string, type: 'text', name: string, position: number): PackagedGuildChannel

function packageMessage(id: string, type: 'dm' | 'unknown'): PackagedChannel

function packageMessage(id: string, type: PackagedChannelType, name?: string, position?: number): PackagedChannel | PackagedGuildChannel

function packageMessage(id: string, type: PackagedChannelType, name?: string, position?: number): PackagedChannel | PackagedGuildChannel {
    return type === 'text' ? { id, type, name, position } : { id, type };
}
```

Comment: Much better now )